# Are electrostatic charges still?

Tags: electrostatics

What happens when a conductor's surface is charged ore when charge is transferred to an insulator at a given location?

Is there any difference between the two cases? Are the charges absorbed by the lattice, do they sit still or do the move, oscillate or orbit?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Macroscopically, as a first answer you can think of the charges in an insulator as being localized. On the other hand the electrons on a metal are not localized and are free to move.

If you were to take a balloon which is an insulator and stick a charge on it the charge would stay localized on the spot where it first landed. It would not be free to move anywhere on the balloon.

On the other hand if you added a charge to a metal ball, the charge is free to move anywhere on the surface of the ball. The motion of the charges on the surface will be random a result of electrons colliding with the metal atoms.

Comment: Thanks,:They say that it is impossible to confine an electron, to make it stay still, how can a charge be still on an insulator? 2) if a conductor is charged, the charges will spread equidistantly on its surface , how can they move around?

Comment: Note in my description that I gave a macroscopic description. Yes, you are correct and so is your source. If you were to examine an extra electron on an insulator microscopically... assuming you were able to observe it, it would be moving very quickly, however its motion would be localized. If you look for instance at a plastic which is made up of molecules the electrons motion would be confined to the vicinity of a molecule. The excess electron would be bound and would have its own orbital. To move from one molecule to the other the electron would have to overcome a binding energy.